# Repair leak on rain gutter

Tags: leak, gutters

Can somebody suggest me a good way to repair a leak in the rain gutter? The rain gutter consists of coated iron sheet metal, it is not in the traditional semicircle form but it is bended to an rectangular cross section. Exactly in the middle of an inner corner there is a leak (~ 3 x 10 mm). Somebody already tried to repair it with some sort of sealant but over the years that ripped open, allowing water to leak in the wooden substructure.

I have no possibility to access the underside of the rain gutter, I would prefer a spot repair since the rest of the gutter is in good shape.

Comment: I don't think I've ever seen a semicircular rain gutter. Anyway, what do you mean that you don't have access to it?

Comment: @isherwood the rain gutter is embedded in some sort of wooden housing (apparently the architect wanted to try something new)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ideally you'd disassemble the corner and replace parts so you can start fresh. Sealant over sealant is a low-percentage approach.

Otherwise, it's a matter of scraping away as much of the old sealant as you can, cleaning the surface well (maybe with alcohol), and using one of the purpose-made sealants. It must be extremely flexible to handle movement due to temperature variation.

Answer (score 1):

If you can't replace and access is difficult, using a sealant may be best. You can get adhesive sealants designed for this job, they can be applied underwater, unlike some silicone sealants.

[Example video of typical product](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FM1FNrwLxZw) - other brands exist.